# Cucumber - steps parametrization

Tags: cucumber

I am very new to Cucumber.

I know (and I use it a lot) that cucumber steps may have parameters in double quotes, like the one below:

```
 And Choose "Ice Cream" from list to add to Order

 # or 

 And User fills in "'<'Name'>'" and "'<'Surname'>'" in the form
 
Examples: TestData      
| Name    | Surname |       
| Michael | Good    |
```

However,
I noticed that there can be steps with a parameters in a single quotes like:

```
And User click 'Create Order' button

# or 

And 'Brush Type' displayed on 'View Order' page
```

I looked into steps, test definitions, page object definitions for the steps described and I can not understand what is the purpose of single quotes.

There would be no difference should it be like:

```
And Brush Type displayed on View Order page
```

Could somebody give me a brief answer, please.
Or send me a link where I can read, please.

Comment: In a step definition, Gherkin language specification allows using `"double quotes"` or `'single quote'` for a `{string}` argument. Please check https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-expressions#readme

Comment: Yes, Thank you , it does make sense now.  I tried single 'quotes' tried it with Cucumber Expression and it does work:                                                                      And User fills in Values '11013', 'Insurance12345670890', '10 hours'                     @And ("User fills in Values {string}, {string}, {string}") 
public void user_fills_nvaluess(String Value1, String Value2, String Value3) just for an experiment I tried to use single quotes with regular expression, it did not work.

Comment: Cucumber prints a code snippet in terminal/console when a step definition is missing. The step definition in your comment works. But please compare the snippet with your implementation. You may also check if you are using latest cucumber-jvm. https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/?lang=java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried single 'quotes' tried it with Cucumber Expression and it does work:
And User fills in Values '11013', 'Insurance12345670890', '10 hours'
@And ("User fills in Values {string}, {string}, {string}")
public void user_fills_nvaluess(String Value1, String Value2, String Value3)

just for an experiment I tried to use single quotes with regular expression, it did not work.